# How i can store all content from <p> tag in array using javascript and jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Following is the code i am working on

```js
var all=$('p').text();
var len_all=$('p').length;
var all_array=[];
for (var i=0; i < len_all; i++) {
  console.log(all);
  all_array.push(all);
}
console.log(all_array);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>I am out</p>
<p>I am in</p>
```

I want all the `<p>` tag contents in `var all_array=[];`
I am getting following output in console:

> (2) ['I am outI am in', 'I am outI am in']

Expected is:

> ['I am out','I am in']

Answer (score 2):

That's because the `$('p').text();` will get the `text` of all `p` elements.

You can achieve  your goal with one line of `vanilla javascript`, to get all `p` elements by `querySelectorAll` and `map` to get each element `textContent`

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<p>I am out</p>
<p>I am in</p>
<script>
let all_array = [...document.querySelectorAll('p')].map(el => el.textContent);
console.log(all_array)
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're getting all of the values as one big value here:

```
var all=$('p').text();
```

And then repeatedly pushing that same value into an array:

```
all_array.push(all);
```

Instead, loop over the `<p>` elements and push *each* value to the array:

```js
var pElements = $('p');
var result = [];
pElements.each(function (i, el) {
  result.push($(el).text());
});
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>I am out</p>
<p>I am in</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
var all=$('p');
var len_all=$('p').length;
var all_array=[];
for (var i=0; i < len_all; i++) {
  console.log(all[i].text());
  all_array.push(all[i].text());
}
console.log(all_array)
```

Or

```
var all=$('p');
var len_all=$('p').length;
var all_array=[];
for (var i=0; i < len_all; i++) {
  console.log($(all[i]).text());
  all_array.push($(all[i]).text());
}
console.log(all_array)
```